# Bubble animation in Google map marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How to make bubble blink animation around marker in Google Map in android which implemented in Swiggy

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following documentation

https://github.com/gursuasik/GoogleMapsRippleEffect

## Download

#### Using Gradle: under dependencies section:

```
compile 'com.github.aarsy.googlemapsrippleeffect:googlemapsrippleeffect:1.0.2'
```

Example is given below

```
// mMap is GoogleMap object, latLng is the location on map from which ripple should start

mapRipple = new MapRipple(mMap, latLng, context);
mapRipple.withNumberOfRipples(3);
mapRipple.withFillColor(Color.BLUE);
mapRipple.withStrokeColor(Color.BLACK);
mapRipple.withStrokewidth(10);      // 10dp
mapRipple.withDistance(2000);      // 2000 metres radius
mapRipple.withRippleDuration(12000);    //12000ms
mapRipple.withTransparency(0.5f);
mapRipple.startRippleMapAnimation();
```